# pulling session attribute from url into webpage

Tags: java, html

From the URL of a page I want the "name" attribute to be displayed on the HTML page like let's say, `Welcome ${name}`

For example, `localhost:8080/index?name=dave`, then in the HTML page it should display as mentioned above.

Main question is what is the syntax to pull it onto an HTML page? As in JSP, it is `${name}` but I don't know for HTML.

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    
    @RequestMapping("index")
    public String index(HttpServletRequest req) {
        
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        if (name != null) {
            System.out.println("Hi! " + name);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }
        session.setAttribute("name", name);
        return "index";
    }
    
}
```

The console displays the text `name="Dave"`, but in the page with URL `localhost:8080/index?name=Dave`, I have typed `Welcome ${name}`, but the name doesn't show up.